# Express Async Method in Method

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, express, async-await

I´m quite new to ExpressJS, so i have a question about my Code.

```
    router.post("/create", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    pruefungController.create(req, res);
});


public async create(req: Request, res: Response): Promise<void> {
        const pruefung = new Pruefung({
            fach: req.body.fach,
            datum: req.body.datum,
            raum: req.body.raum
        });
        await pruefung.save();
        res.send(pruefung);
    }
```

Is it enough to declare the create method as async or do i have to declare the callback also as async like this?

```
router.post("/create", async (req: Request, res: Response) => {
    await pruefungController.create(req, res);
});
```

In my opinion it should be enough to just await the action of the .save() method, but i don´t know how Express handles the method passed into the router.post() method :(

Comment: A problem with your code is that you don't have any error handling.  If `await pruefunc.save();` gets an error, you don't handle that error and don't send an error response to the http request.  In fact, your code will generate an uncaught rejection warning.  Note, it appears like you probably also aren't validating the three parameters you're using from `req.body` so they could be anything, including things that would cause your code to fail.

Comment: You mean, i should handle it with something like "pruefungController.create(req, res).catch(...)?

Comment: Either that or use `try/catch` within the create funtion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only time you need to declare a function as `async` is if you use the `await` keyword inside it.

The only time you need to use the `await` keyword is if you need a function to wait for a promise to resolve before continuing.

The function you pass to `post` doesn't do anything after calling `pruefungController.create`. Nor does anything care about the value it returns. You don't need to use `await` there so you don't need to make it `async`.

For that matter, that function doesn't do *anything* except call another function with the same arguments, so you can get rid of it:

```
router.post("/create", pruefungController.create);
```